# JMeter :: Parameterization Query for mapping test data with user ID

Tags: jmeter, parameterization

The issue is with JMeter parameterization Logic. 
I have a csv file with user id and pwd - which is fine
Another CSV has 10 records, one for each user ID. How do I map these records to user ids?

Csv1:
UserID, Pwd
TestUser1, Password1
TestUser2, Password1

CSV2:
Record
Rec1forUser1
Rec2forUser1
Rec3forUser1
Rec1forUser2
Rec2forUser2

and so on..

How do I arrange the mapping when multiple users (say 2) are going to run for a Loop of 3 records each.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We have some best practices here what should be included in a good question. They ensure that your question is clear, that people can help you efficiently and that your question is of value to future readers. In your case, I recommend you invest a few minutes to create a [mcve]. Then [edit] your question to include it. You will find that your questions can be answered much quicker then. In general, make sure you've read our guide [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible with standard JMeter equipment, what you're asking for.

I would suggest to use the User data set as a driver, and for the record read at each iteration then split second dataset to separate files (1 per user), then ingest 'em in the custom JSR223 element - actually, the file operations toolset Groovy equipped with makes that task pretty easy, smth. like:

```
new File(path + userID + "_someSuffix.csv").eachLine { line ->
    line.split(',').each { field ->
        ... use fields here somehow ...
    }
}
```

In case you have to have multiple iterations per user, you probably would have to read the Users dataset that way as well.

And finally, yet another way is to denormalize/flatten your dataset: include (repetitive) User records into second dataset along with data belonging to user, like:

```
TestUser1, Password1, Rec1forUser1 
TestUser1, Password1, Rec2forUser1
TestUser1, Password1, Rec3forUser1
```

That may not look pretty, but would do the job.